# Hide jquery code on mobile devices

Tags: jquery

I implemented bootstrap menu inside prestashop.

Because bootstrap doesn't support hover menu (only after a click), I'm using the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768){

        $('li.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown();
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideUp();
        });

    }
});
```

I want this slidedown hover effect to be visible on screen resolutions of 768 and above; and not on mobile devices. But the code above doesn't really work.

I also tried to use the code below without succes.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
if (winWidth > 768) {...}
```

Anyone else an idea; someone who's more skilled at jquery than me. 
Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What does `console.log(window.innerWidth)` show?

Comment: window.innerWidth is normally 1280, when resized to a smaller view, it's 691px. With 691px  the slideup and down also works , which shouldn't be the case. Will update my post with a screenshot. :)

Comment: Your code is only running when the page is loaded. If you resize, nothing runs it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this way, you could as well support window resize by checking width when hovering :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            // expected behavior on large screen
        }
    }, function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            // expected behavior on large screen
        }
    })
});
```

does this help ?